# Breeze manager.createEntity not working

Tags: breeze

I'm working with the todo Breeze/Angular app and `return manager.createEntity('TodoItem', initialValues);` does not seem to be doing anything.  There is no error in the browser when I go to create a new item.  Editing existing items is working exactly as expected.
What could be causing this?  I'm using a database first entity model and the Id is an identity column generated by the database.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the MetaData has been pulled in. Check the network dialog and see if you have a call to the getMetaData method for the TodoController.

If not call fetchMetadata

```
var serviceurl = "/breeze/endpoint";
var manager = breeze.Entitymanager(serviceurl);
manager.fetchMetadata();
```

Also make sure that the datacontext/dataservice is calling the adapter. This is required for the Angular Framework.

```
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("modelLibrary", "backingStore", true);
```

PS I am new to Breezejs so please take my help as intended... I am no expert... yet :)

Comment: I checked these things and they were not the cause.  I failed to see the error that was generated, please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was an error and I missed it (I'm very new to this):

Cannot attach an object to an EntityManager without first setting its key or setting its entityType 'AutoGeneratedKeyType' property to something other than 'None'

I went into my entity model and changed the StoreGeneratedPattern on the Id property of the TodoItem entity from none to Identity.  I built the project and then it worked.